# Symfony inject service container into doctrine connection wrapper

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I try to inject the symfony service container into a dcotrine dynamic connection wrapper_class

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;    
class DynamicConnection extends Connection
{
    public $container;

    /**
     * @required
     * @param $container
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

I also tried to inject it with the service.yaml

```
    App\Service\Database\DynamicConnection:
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

But this is also not working. How can i inject the service container here?
My goal here is to get a variable of the service container:

```
$this->container->get('my.string.variable')
```

Comment: Doctrine itself knows nothing about the container.  Doctrine creates the connections using the new operator.  There is simply no place to hook in a container that I know of.  You could access the container globally ($kernel->getContainer()) though that tends to be frowned upon.  Maybe a [kernel request listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-request-event) that modifies the connection early in the request processing cycle.  But don't inject the whole container if all you need is a parameter.

Comment: And if you are not using the entity manager at all then it is easy enough to [define your own doctrine connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620275/how-to-register-the-dbal-doctrine-connection-as-a-service-without-the-doctrinebu/47635677#47635677) completely independent of the doctrine bundle.

Comment: Ok, global $kernel; $kernel->getContainer(); worked for me. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just be aware that using globals in Symfony is considered to be a very very bad thing indeed.  Ultimately it would be better to learn how to do things the "right" way.

Comment: I found that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53301465/4640060) very useful in your case

Comment: If all you want is a parameter, why not put it as a env variable and use getenv() instead ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a `CompilerPass`. For simple `CompilerPass`, you can add it directly in your application `Kernel` class by implementing `CompilerPassInterface`:

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    ...


    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {

       $container
          ->getDefinition('doctrine.dbal.default_connection')
          ->addMethodCall('setContainer', [
             new Reference('service_container')
           ]);
    }

}
```

Note however that as mentioned by other users, this is not a very good practice. You should inject what you need precisely instead of Container service.

Answer (score 0):

*Not exactly injecting the Container (bad practice), but supposing we want to do inject any service.*

Constructor injection was not right for me, it needed plenty of other parameters, which should be coming from configurations:

```
 public function __construct(
        #[SensitiveParameter]
        array $params,
        protected Driver $driver,
        ?Configuration $config = null,
    )
```

Setter injection did not work for me (I assume the wrapper class is not going through the dependency injection process, just the class is being passed to the Connection initialization?).

I did not want to build an extra compiler pass for that.

Since neither constructor injection, nor setter injection, nor compiler pass were fit for me, I just used Adapter pattern. I created a new service that was easilly constructor-injectable, which calls DBAL Connection methods.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Infrastructure\Database;

use App\Business\Security\Authenticator;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection as DoctrineDBALConnection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder;

final class Connection
{
    private DoctrineDBALConnection $connection;
    private Authenticator $authenticator;

    public function __construct(DoctrineDBALConnection $connection, Authenticator $authenticator)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->authenticator = $authenticator;
    }

    public function createQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder
    {
        // to your extra stuff here
        return $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
    }
}
```